# Making a promise business logic check, but wont work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, promise

So I´m making a web app with node, express and mongo (no front end yet) and trying to check that a registerging user ain´t using an email that already used as follows:

```
const existsTatuador = (db, tatuador) =>{
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        tatuadorDB.findTatuador(db, docs => {
            docs.forEach(element => {
                if(element.correo == tatuador.correo){
                    reject(Error("lo logro, el hijo de puta lo logro"));
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

}

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
mongo.getDatabase(db =>{
    tatuadorLogic.existsTatuador(db, req.body).then(
        tatuadorDB.insertTatuador(db, data =>{
            console.log("Inicia el proceso para crear el tatuador :" );
            console.log(req.body);
            res.send(req.body);
        }, req.body)
    ).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
})});
```

});

But for some reason when the reject of the promise is called it is going to the catch block after doing the .then() and I get Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: You never resolve the promise in `existsTatuador()`.

Comment: I added the resolve right afte the end of the foreach and still have the issue

Comment: You appear to be retrieving all users into your application, from the db, and then searching for a matching email. Am I reading that right? I'd expect a query sent to the db.

Comment: What does `tatuadorDB.findTatuador` do? Does it return a promise? Is the second parameter the query to be run against the DB, or the callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several issues:

1. You aren't resolving your promise in `existsTatuador()`.
2. `.then()` needs a function reference to be passed to it, not the result of executing your function.
3. `tatuadorDB.insertTatuador()` does not have any means of returning an error, but it appears to be a database operation which can presumably have an error.
4. You have very little data integrity checking for what is passed in `req.body` which, since it's coming from an unknown client, could literally be anything.

You can fix the first two issues with this:

```
const existsTatuador = (db, tatuador) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        tatuadorDB.findTatuador(db, docs => {
            for (let element of docs) {
                if (element.correo == tatuador.correo) {
                    reject(Error("lo logro, el hijo de puta lo logro"));
                    return;
                }
            }
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
    mongo.getDatabase(db => {
        // this next line shows a fix to how the function is passed to .then()
        tatuadorLogic.existsTatuador(db, req.body).then(() => {
            tatuadorDB.insertTatuador(db, data => {
                console.log("Inicia el proceso para crear el tatuador :" );
                console.log(req.body);
                res.send(req.body);
            }, req.body);
        }).catch((err)=> {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send(err);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks!, but even after those changes the request is still being posted to the database

Comment: @LeonardoMejiaBustos - Still being posted to the database under what circumstances?  What is the actual problem with this code.  Are you just saying that `existsTatuador()` does not `reject()` when it is supposed to?  Your original code was always calling `tatuadorDB.insertTatuador()` event when `existsTatuador()`.  This code does not do that.  If `existsTatuador()` rejects, this code will not insert it into the database.  So, maybe you need to find out why `existsTatuador()` is not rejecting?  That would just take a little debugging on your part.

Comment: well, it actually rejects but it still posts, that´s been the issue since the start

Comment: @LeonardoMejiaBustos - You would have to show me the EXACT code that you claim is doing that because the code I posted here will not.  If `tatuadorLogic.existsTatuador()` rejects, this code will NOT call `tatuadorDB.insertTatuador()`.  Are you 100% sure you fixed problem #2 in my list where you weren't passing the right arguments to `.then()` properly?

Comment: @LeonardoMejiaBustos - Are you sure you're doing `tatuadorLogic.existsTatuador(db, req.body).then(() => {...})` instead of the way you have it in your question?

Comment: @LeonardoMejiaBustos - Also, why don't you just use a database query to find if the appropriate `correo` exists?